# How do I late-resolve * in .csproj files?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have a `.csproj` file that looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>12.0</LangVersion>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="*.dat" />
    <None Include="*.dat" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PrecompileScript" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
    <Exec Command="dotnet run -c $(Configuration) --no-build --project ../DatGenerator/DatGenerator.csproj -directory $(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The problem is `*.dat` is expanded too soon and doesn't actually pick up any files. How do I expand `*.dat` after the `<Exec` directive that emits the `*.dat` runs? No, `-directory $(ProjectDir)/bin/$(Configuration)/$(TargetFramework)` isn't right. That doesn't work at all; see how there isn't a `<OutputType>exe</OutputType>`. The copy build outputs built-in functionality needs to work.

Listing each `.dat` file manually is pretty bad. I need to pick up changes automatically here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To late-resolve a wildcard, move the item `Include` inside a target.

e.g. Change your code to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>12.0</LangVersion>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PrecompileScript" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet run -c $(Configuration) --no-build --project ../DatGenerator/DatGenerator.csproj -directory $(ProjectDir)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="*.dat" />
      <None Include="*.dat" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

"[How MSBuild builds projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022)" explains the evaluation and execution phases but, briefly:

- When building a project, MSBuild has an evaluation phase followed by an executuion phase.
- 'Top level' `PropertyGroup` and `ItemGroup` elements are evaluated in the evalution phase.
- Target order is determined in the evaluation phase.
- Targets are run in the execution phase.
- `PropertyGroup` and `ItemGroup` elements within a target are evaluated when the target is run.

**Note** I updated the answer to change from using `BeforeCompile` to using `BeforeBuild`.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. CopyToOutputDirectory never happens.

Comment: You didn't ask about `CopyToOutputDirectory`. You asked about resolving wildcards. Change from `BeforeCompile` to `BeforeBuild`. `BeforeCompile` is probably too late.

Comment: Ok that works. Ugh; I went up and down through the documentation even before you updated it and can't see why it matters.

Comment: The files that are auto-imported by the `Sdk` attribute include MSBuild targets that check certain item collections (including [`None` and `Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022)) for the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata and build an item collection of the files that need to be copied.  This logic and the actual copying of the files are performed before the `BeforeCompile` target. It is not documented. Or at least not very well . But you can run `/preprocess` and see all the SDK code.